# Url rewrite, add rule, redirect as POST request?

Tags: url-rewriting

its so good to be able to make rewrites:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('^profiles/p$', "index.php?page_id=profilesPageId", "top");
```

but its a GET request. How to make a POST request, or pass POST parameters for the redirected page?

Comment: URLs aren’t post or get, you make post or get requests to URLs. Are you trying to make it so that visiting a URL submits a post request automatically? What for?

Comment: Are you thinking about [Query Vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)?